# Js в куске html кода в переменной js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть переменная

```
$(function() {
'use strict';

var newSelectHtml = '<p>Дата приема</P<input class="cald" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="vtpr"></input>'

$('.js-checkbox').on('click', function() {
$('.js-select-wrap').html(newSelectHtml);
});
});
</script>
```

На самой странице по переключению radio кнопки появляется этот код html, но в нем не работает класс, не показывается календарь, который грузится из другого js скрипта. Как сделать так, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Да, в синтаксисе ошибка есть, но дело в том что если отдельно этот html код вставить в страницу, он будет работать. Так что я думаю дело в чем-то другом

Answer (score 1):

у вас не закрыт тег Р.И к тому же возможно вы скинете другой скрипт тоже.

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать так, чтобы заработало?

Исправить 2 ошибки в разметке?

> ```
> var newSelectHtml = '<p>Дата приема</P<input class="cald" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="vtpr"></input>'
> ```

```
var newSelectHtml = '<p>Дата приема</p><input class="cald" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="vtpr" />';
```